# Special characters in mail (address) headers and RFC2047 encoding

Tags: exim, encoding, rfc

I have some unexpected handling of [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) "From" headers on Exim.

(Actual addresses have been changed, the original display name contained non-ASCII characters)

For this "From" header:

```
From: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Doe=2C_John?= <john@doe.com>
```

Which decodes to

```
From: Doe, John <john@doe.com>
```

The intended equivalent format likely is:

```
From: "Doe, John" <john@doe.com>
```

Exim populates `${addresses:$h_from:}` with `Doe:john@doe.com`, which seems to imply that Exim decodes the string first and then interpret it.

Is this a bug? Should RFC2047 encoded strings in address fields be handled as quoted strings by mail servers? (This make sense, since the interpretation of the header would then be the same from a RFC2047-aware and non-RFC2047-aware mail server, while requiring the quotes in the encoded string allows for things like `To: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Doe@jack.com=2C_John?= <john@doe.com>` to be interpreted differently by different mail software)

An online [RFC2047 decoder](http://dogmamix.com/MimeHeadersDecoder/) useful for decoding the headers

Comment: RFC2047 has: "Furthermore, the characters used in encoded-words are restricted to those which do not have special meanings in the context in which the encoded-word appears.", which might mean that commas in encoded `From:` headers might violate RFC2047.

Answer (score 0):

Using `${addresses:$rh_from:}` instead of `${addresses:$h_from:}` resolves the problem.

This makes Exim extract the addresses from the non-decoded version instead of the decoded version. (`${addresses:<string>}` decodes the string value at that time, which means that if the decoded header, `$h_from` is fed as input, the comma gets interpreted, resulting in the problem seen)